# Finding the class of a variable in R

Tags: r, class, variables

So I have this problem with R. I have a table and I need to find what is the class of the variable (i.e. I'm presuming that would be referring to the data in the columns).

The data is quite big i.e. many rows.

Whenever I write `class(nameofthedata)` it doesn't work and whenever I write `class("titleofthecolumn")` it gives me back "character i.e. referring to the title of the column which is not what I'm after...

Comment: Please post a sample of your data. Just run `dput(head(df))` – replace `df` with whatever your data.frame is called and post the output here so people can more easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: `class("titleofthecolumn")` is `character` because `"titleofthecolumn"` is a string.

Comment: structure(list(schoolid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), score = c(0L, 
10L, 0L, 40L, 42L, 4L), gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("schoolid", 
"score", "gender"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I like using `str` to take a quick look at the variables for the whole data.frame or list. It outputs the type of the variable and some of the values. For particular variables, you can use `class(df[,"varname")` or `typeof(df[,"varname"]`. Here Feeding these functions `df$varname` will also work.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following solution:

```
# Load sample data
data(mtcars)
# Classes
sapply(mtcars, class)
```

You can the convinetly identify classes of all variables in the data frame:

```
>> t(t(sapply(mtcars, class)))
     [,1]     
mpg  "numeric"
cyl  "numeric"
disp "numeric"
hp   "numeric"
drat "numeric"
wt   "numeric"
qsec "numeric"
vs   "numeric"
am   "numeric"
gear "numeric"
carb "numeric"
```

*`t()` used only for the code presentation.*

Comment: Wonder if just `str(mtcars)` won't be enough

Comment: @DavidArenburg Would be in terms of the returned information, but from my personal perspective the output is less useful. Have a look at `class(sapply(mtcars, class))` and `class(str(mtcars))`. `sapply` results can be easily manipulated. Personally, in [tag:rstudio] i often do `View(t(t(sapply(data, class))))` to spit out convenience `data.frame` and skim through variable list and look at the types.

Comment: `as.matrix(stuff)` is perhaps easier to read that `t(t(stuff))`

Comment: @lebatsnok True, old habits die hard.

Comment: Dear Konrad, I don't quite get what you mean... where shall I insert the name of the dataset? Instead of the t? what does mcasrs stand for?

Comment: `data(mtcars)` is not necessary.  If fact `data()` is never necessary for base data sets

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the class of a specific column, say `schoolid`, just call `class()` on that column, like so:

```
df <- structure(list(schoolid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                     score = c(0L, 10L, 0L, 40L, 42L, 4L),
                     gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)),
                     .Names = c("schoolid", "score", "gender"),
                     row.names = c(NA, 6L),
                     class = "data.frame")

class(df$schoolid)
# returns [1] "integer"
```

If you want to know the classes of all columns, you can apply `class()` to all columns using `sapply()`:

```
sapply(df, class)
```

Comment: Thanks. I received this data set so I'm still trying to understand it. What is the "1L" in schoolid? and the 0L, 10L etc in score?  As there are 3 columns and many rows, I can't understand where the 6 item is represented...

Comment: I also have another question: So I have this column in a data set which represente gender (male or female)
male is represented by 1 and female is represented by 0. I have to switch the two i.e. male has to be represented by 0 and female by 1. I've been trying to fix this for hours, so far without success. Any help?

Comment: `1L` is just R-internal representation for the integer 1. You should never see it that way in practice, it just appears in the dput to differentiate it from the floating point number 1.0.

Comment: `df$gender <- ifelse(df$gender==1,0,1)` should do it. That makes `gender` `0` if it was previously `1` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Alternatively, you could actually give the genders proper names: `df$gender <- as.factor(ifelse(df$gender==1,'male','female'))` will give you a categorical/factor variable.

Comment: Another question: When one has to find the relationship between two variables i.e. two columns, is there any other way other than cor(nameofdataset)?